# Recursively finding the path to a node in a Binary Tree

Tags: java, path, binary-tree, nodes

I know the node being searched for is in the unsorted binary tree, but I can't figure out how to pass my path back through the recursive calls. My two functions: one finds the path to a specific node, and the other returns a string of paths to all nodes. A 0 indicates a left path is taken and a 1 a right.

```
private static String getAllPaths(final BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root)
{
    // TO DO
    String path = "";
    String returnStr = "";
    return getAP(root, path, returnStr);
}

private static String getAP(BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, String path,
        String returnStr) 
{
    returnStr += "" + root.getData() + " " + path + "\n";
    if(root.hasLeftChild())
        getAP( root.getLeftChild(), path.concat("0"), returnStr);
    if(root.hasRightChild())
        getAP( root.getRightChild(), path.concat("1"), returnStr);

    return returnStr;
}

private static String getPathTo(final BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, char c)
{
    // TO DO
    String path = "";
    if( root.getData() == c )
        return path;

    if( root.hasLeftChild() )
    {
        String s = getPathTo(root.getLeftChild(), c);

        if( s != null )
        {
            path += "0";
            path += s;
            return path;
        }
    }

    if( root.hasRightChild() )
    {
        String s = getPathTo(root.getRightChild(), c);

        if( s != null )
        {
            path += "1";
            path += s;
            return path;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I am terrible at recursion, so any help at all is greatly appreciated. I got it all to work. Above code is good now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable in java. When you pass a `String` to a method a whole new value is created. For example:

```
void modifyString(String x) {
    x += "(modified)";
}
```

If you use the method:

```
String s = "myString!";
modifyString(s);
// what does s equal?
```

You might expect `s == "myString!(modified)"`, but this isn't true.

In your case, you are passing `returnStr` as a parameter to recursive calls to `getAP`. However it is not modified as you assume. To fix it, append the result of the recursive method calls to the local `returnStr` and return that.

```
// removed returnStr as a parameter
private static String getAP(BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, String path) 
{
    String returnStr = "" + root.getData() + " " + path + "\n";
    if(root.hasLeftChild())
        returnStr += getAP( root.getLeftChild(), path.concat("0")); 
    if(root.hasRightChild())
        returnStr += getAP( root.getRightChild(), path.concat("1"));

    return returnStr;
}
```

I glanced at your `getPT` method and I don't actually see any obvious problem with it.